# Парсинг URL регулярками PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Товарищи, пишу парсер ссылок

```
"https://domain.ru:8080/folder/subfolder/../././?var1=val1&var2=val2"
"https://http.google.com/folder/././?var1=val1&var2=val2",
"ftp://mail.ru/?hello=world&url=https://http.google.com/folder//././?var1=val1&var2=val2",
```

что нужно исправить в регулярке что бы результат был корректен при отсутствие любой части ссылки ( если нет протокола то все ок если нет домена то тоже все ок, проблемы с путем - регулярка считает то что написано в параметрах за путь : иными словами что нужно исправить : что бы регулярка не лезла в параметры)

вот моя регулярка :

```
$_re = 
    "~^
        (?:(?<protocol>http|https|ftp):\\/\\/)?                  

        (?<domain_name>
            (?<domain_2_lvl>[a-z0-9\.]+)
            \.
            (?<zone>[a-z]{2,4})
            :?(?<port>[0-9]{4})?
        )?

        |(?<raw_folder> ((?<=\/)([a-z.]+)(?=\/)))
        |(?<script>script.php)?
        |\?
        |(?<key>[a-z0-9?\/_]+)=(?<value>[a-z0-9?\/_]+)?
    ~ix"

preg_match_all($_re, $__url, $matches);
```

Comment: Почему регулярка и чем [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) не угодил?

Comment: А чего вы добиться хотите? В php есть функция для парсинга url, так и называется ;) [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: я хочу поработать с регулярными выражениями. Это просто учебная задача - для того что бы понять как все устроено.

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex Здесь есть примеры всяких url и регулярки

Comment: Но все же, как в этой ситуации(которая выше) сделать так что бы регулярка была актуальна если отсутствует какая то часть ссылки?

Comment: Вот к примеру [https://regex101.com/r/2BL9Wf/1](https://regex101.com/r/2BL9Wf/1), а домен парсить через функцию `explode`

Comment: не плохо,  но я хотел собрать регулярку которая была бы универсальной для любой ссылки без использования других функций по работе со строками

Comment: Ну это ты прям много хочешь))) Я однажды тоже в академических целях регулярку писал для парсинга даты с учётом количества дней в месяце и високосных годов, на 1к символов вышла)))

Comment: Скил норм прокачал? :) смотри я дал ответ, кажется норм

Comment: Ага, теперь не занимаюсь такой ерундой :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить альтернативу `|` и "просмотры" вперёд и назад, а пустые элементы в массиве отфильтровать:

```
$url = 'https://domain.ru:8080/folder/subfolder/../././?var1=val1&var2=val2';

$patt = '~^
    (?:(?<protocol>(?:ht|f)tps?)://)?
    (?<domain_name>
        (?<domain_2_lvl>[\pL\d.-]+)?
        \.
        (?<zone>\pL{2,4})
        (?::(?<port>\d{4}))?
    )?
    | (?<raw_folder>(?<=/)[\pL.]+(?=/))
~ix';

preg_match_all($patt, $url, $matches);
$matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);
```

Результат:

```
var_dump(
    $matches['protocol'],     // https
    $matches['domain_name'],  // domain.ru:8080
    $matches['domain_2_lvl'], // domain
    $matches['zone'],         // ru
    $matches['port'],         // 8080
    $matches['raw_folder']    /* array (size=5)
        1 => string 'folder' (length=6)
        2 => string 'subfolder' (length=9)
        3 => string '..' (length=2)
        4 => string '.' (length=1)
        5 => string '.' (length=1)
    */
);
```

Comment: с такой ссылкой :                                                                        "mail.ru/?hello=world&url=https://http.google.com/folder//././?var1=val1&var2=val2?mail=ru"                                                          
не работает

Comment: @СuriousBoy так у вас в вопросе и не было таких ссылок. Пример написан для `/folder/subfolder/../././` -- именно это вы просили.

Comment: согласен,тогда подскажите как обрабатывать ситуации когда в ссылке не указан путь,а если быть точным то может отсутствовать любая часть ссылки

Comment: @СuriousBoy ваша регулярка в комплекте с моей вполне справляется с этой задачей. Шаблоны написаны для большинства урлов, всё предусмотреть можно попытаться, но зачем, если для этого есть встроенные инструменты.

Comment: В этом интересно разобраться, у меня не получается это сделать и я хочу что бы все таки получилось. Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Comment: В ссылке которую я указал в первом коментарии нету пути,но выражение                                                                                                      | (?<raw_folder>(?<=/)[\pL.]+(?=/))                                                                считаает то что написано в параметрах за путь, как сделать так что ты ругялярка не лезла в параметры?

Comment: @СuriousBoy вероятно нужно сделать обязательной первую часть в шаблоне, там где определяется протокол http и ему подобные.

Comment: но протокол тоже может отсутствовать

Comment: @СuriousBoy а по какому тогда принципу понять, что это именно url, а не обычная строка? Это же противоречие, вы так не думаете? Если нет обязательной части с протоколом, то скорее всего точно определять урлы не получится, а приблизительно вы уже определили.

Comment: Принцип такой: может отсутствовать любая часть ссылки. Если задачу поставить таким образом - то она имеет решение,верно? Давайте обсудим его

Comment: @СuriousBoy вот между этим _может отсутствовать любая часть ссылки._ и этим _но выражение | (?<raw_folder>(?<=/)[\pL.]+(?=/)) считаает то что написано в параметрах за путь_ лично я вижу противоречие: если может отсутствовать любая часть урла, то мой шаблон вполне правильно находит совпадение для той строки.

Comment: все верно, регулярка не должна считать то что написано в параметрах за путь, но она считает что это путь

Comment: @СuriousBoy вы можете отредактировать ваш пост с вопросом, перечислив варианты урлов, для которых нужно искать соответствия, и на их основе я позже допишу код в свой ответ.

Comment: так и сделаем..)

Answer (score 0):

Совместными усилиями получилось

```
 $_re = 
    "~^
    (?:(?<protocol>http|https|ftp):\\/\\/)?                  
    (?<domain_name>
        (?<domain_2_lvl>[a-z0-9\.]+)
        \.
        (?<zone>[a-z]{2,4})
        :?(?<port>[0-9]{4})?
    )?
    |(?<raw_folder> ((?<=\/)([a-z.]+)(?=\/)))
    |(?<script>script.php)?
    |(?<key>[a-z0-9\/_]+)=(?<value>[a-z0-9?\/_:.]+)
    ~ix";
```

Подкорректируйте, если я ошибаюсь